# meteor template: input value depending on given values

Tags: templates, meteor

I want to set the value of an input field depending on some values: If `valueMin` and `valueMax` are defined, the result should be

```
<input type="text" value="{{valueDef}}({{valueMin}}-{{valueMax}})">
```

Otherwise it should be

```
<input type="text" value="{{valueDef}}">
```

So the values of the input could be

```
12
34(1-50)
```

What is the best way to realize that in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If neither *valueMin* nor *valueMax* can be zero then you can just write:

```
{{#if valueMin}}
  {{#if valueMax}}
    <input type="text" value="{{valueDef}}({{valueMin}}-{{valueMax}})">
  {{else}}
    <input type="text" value="{{valueDef}}">
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Otherwise you can just define a single helper that evaluates the existence of both variables and then use that in an `{{#if switch}}`

js:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  switch: function(){
    return typeof(this.valueMin) === 'number' && typeof(this.valueMax) === 'number';
  }
});
```

html:

```
{{#if switch}}
  <input type="text" value="{{valueDef}}({{valueMin}}-{{valueMax}})">
{{else}}
  <input type="text" value="{{valueDef}}">
{{/if}}
```